# JDBC Driver for TigerGraph DB

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea, tigergraph

I am trying to connect to Tigergraph DB from Spark using IntelliJ IDE. Can anyone help with the jdbc driver (.jar) file? I am looking for "com.tigergraph.jdbc.Driver".

I did find below gitHub repository with all the required .java file. But, I am not sure how to use it inside my spark project. https://github.com/tigergraph/ecosys/tree/master/tools/etl/tg-jdbc-driver

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done quickly. I hope you are familiar with maven and git.

1. [[Command prompt]] git clone https://github.com/tigergraph/ecosys.git
2. Navigate to [[project checkout path]]\ecosys\tools\etl\tg-jdbc-driver
3. execute mvn clean compile install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

and then, once build is okay you will get the JAR in the folder

[image]

[image]

You can use this JAR afterwards in your project.

Comment: by any chance, is it possible for you to share those .jar files? I am completely new to all this.

Comment: @Surya You can also build JARs using IntelliJ IDEA if you are not familiar with git & Maven (video guide [#1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xo6zSBgdgk), [#2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlyTn8PZ3Fc))

Comment: Thanks @J.P for uploading the jar files into GitHub. I figured out how to build using Maven. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

according to the GitHub documentation of tg-jdbc-driver repository, you need to build the JAR and then you can include this dependency in your pom.xml and start using it's API.

Some helpful resources:

https://medium.com/tigergraph/data-lakes-will-yield-more-business-value-when-combined-with-graph-databases-928181dffe24

https://www.programmersought.com/article/68114478380/